# Compare multiple target document with multiple source document

Tags: python, analysis

I am a beginner to AI and sentimental analysis. I'm doing sentimental analysis between two documents. This code is working perfectly fine when I add only one source document rather than a list of multiple source documents to compare it with multiple target documents.

Can someone please tell me what I need to change to work it with multiple source documents list?

```
#Loading pre=trained word2vec model

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

# You need to dowload google pre-trained model using below link
# https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit
#Change the path according to your directory

model_path = 'E:\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300.bin'   
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)



#Setting Parameters for model

class DocSim(object):
    def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
        self.w2v_model = w2v_model
        self.stopwords = stopwords

    def vectorize(self, doc):
        """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
        doc = doc.lower()
        words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
        word_vecs = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                vec = self.w2v_model[word]
                word_vecs.append(vec)
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore, if the word doesn't exist in the vocabulary
                pass

        # Assuming that document vector is the mean of all the word vectors

        vector = np.mean(word_vecs, axis=0)
        return vector


    def _cosine_sim(self, vecA, vecB):
        """Find the cosine similarity distance between two vectors."""
        csim = np.dot(vecA, vecB) / (np.linalg.norm(vecA) * np.linalg.norm(vecB))
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim

    def calculate_similarity(self, source_doc, target_docs=[], threshold=0):
        """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source document & all
        the target documents."""
        if isinstance(target_docs, str):
            target_docs = [target_docs]


        source_vec = self.vectorize(source_doc)
        results = []
        for doc in target_docs:
            target_vec = self.vectorize(doc)
            sim_score = self._cosine_sim(source_vec, target_vec)
            if sim_score > threshold:
                results.append({
                    'score' : sim_score,
                    'doc' : doc
                })
            # Sort results by score in desc order
            results.sort(key=lambda k : k['score'] , reverse=True)

        return results


ds = DocSim(w2v_model)



#Calculate the similarity score between a source rule & a target rule.

source_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.2.3 Value']
target_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.1.2.4 Assist Failed Train']

# This will return one target rules text with a similarity score

sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity(source_rule, target_rule)

print(sim_scores)
```

This is the error I am getting right now.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-041084a3f599> in <module>
      6 # This will return one target rules text with similarity score
      7 
----> 8 sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity(source_rule, target_rule)
      9 
     10 print(sim_scores)

<ipython-input-20-055f5d25808f> in calculate_similarity(self, source_doc, target_docs, threshold)
     41             source_doc=[source_doc]
     42 
---> 43         source_vec = self.vectorize(source_doc)
     44         results = []
     45         for doc in target_docs:

<ipython-input-20-055f5d25808f> in vectorize(self, doc)
      8     def vectorize(self, doc):
      9         """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
---> 10         doc = doc.lower()
     11         words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
     12         word_vecs = []

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Your `vectorize()` function expects a string document and is transforming it to lowercase using the `lower()` function. But you are passing a list of documents to `vectorize()` and hence it can't convert a list to lowercase which raises the error. Either provide the documents one at a time to the `vectorize()` function or change the `vectorize()` function to handle multiple documents at a time.

Comment: In it's current form, I think the code might be setup to perform one to many comparisions rather than many to many (which you want). You could just loop over the source documents and go through the one to many process multiple times.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to vectorize() function to handle multiple documents at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than sending the whole list to the function, make sure the `source_rule` is a list and then iterate over it and then execute the `calculate_similarity()` function on it

```
#Loading pre=trained word2vec model

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

# You need to dowload google pre-trained model using below link
# https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit
#Change the path according to your directory

model_path = 'E:\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300.bin'   
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)



#Setting Parameters for model

class DocSim(object):
    def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
        self.w2v_model = w2v_model
        self.stopwords = stopwords

    def vectorize(self, doc):
        """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
        doc = doc.lower()
        words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
        word_vecs = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                vec = self.w2v_model[word]
                word_vecs.append(vec)
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore, if the word doesn't exist in the vocabulary
                pass

        # Assuming that document vector is the mean of all the word vectors

        vector = np.mean(word_vecs, axis=0)
        return vector


    def _cosine_sim(self, vecA, vecB):
        """Find the cosine similarity distance between two vectors."""
        csim = np.dot(vecA, vecB) / (np.linalg.norm(vecA) * np.linalg.norm(vecB))
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim

    def calculate_similarity(self, source_doc, target_docs=[], threshold=0):
        """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source document & all
        the target documents."""
        if isinstance(target_docs, str):
            target_docs = [target_docs]


        source_vec = self.vectorize(source_doc)
        results = []
        for doc in target_docs:
            target_vec = self.vectorize(doc)
            sim_score = self._cosine_sim(source_vec, target_vec)
            if sim_score > threshold:
                results.append({
                    'score' : sim_score,
                    'doc' : doc
                })
            # Sort results by score in desc order
            results.sort(key=lambda k : k['score'] , reverse=True)

        return results


ds = DocSim(w2v_model)



#Calculate the similarity score between a source rule & a target rule.

source_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.2.3 Value']
target_rule = [ '2.1.1 Context','2.1.2.4 Assist Failed Train']

if isinstance(source_rule, str):
    source_rule = [source_rule]

# This will return one target rules text with a similarity score
for rule in source_rule:
    sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity(rule, target_rule)

    print("Similarity with {} is {}".format(rule, sim_scores))
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'source_rule' referenced before assignment

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the value of source rule before you run the loop?

Comment: I am formatted exactly like you have done and now getting older error.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: That was a tiny typo. in the second last line, pass rule instead of source_rule. I've edited the answer to show that

Comment: Haha. No worries. Glad I could help. Upvote as well if it helped.

Comment: Hello, You helped me a couple of months back if you can help me with a new issue.I am trying to format my output of the code using pandas. Your help would be greatly appreciated